# Scale only dataset read from file without scaling whole graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, scaling

I have datasets which vary strong in range. So i want to scale my dataset to adjust it to my template, so that the grids, axes and so on are identical with the neighbour-subfigures.

What is the easiest way to do this?

As mentioned I don't want the scale whole image.

It's like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

 \draw[step=0.2cm, very thin,color=black!20] (-0.01,-0.01) grid (2.09,1.19);
    \draw[->] (-0,0) -- (2.09,0) node[right] {$t$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.19) node[above] {$y_1$};

    \foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,2.1}  \node[anchor=north, font=\tiny] at (\x,0) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=1,decimalsymbol=comma]{\x}};
    \foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,1.1}  \node[anchor=east, font=\tiny] at (0,\y) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=1,decimalsymbol=comma]{\y}};


     \draw[thick] plot file {Grafik/tikz/fr_t.dat}  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't want to scale the whole picture but only dataset and y-axis values. Something like

```
.
.
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,10.1}   \node...
\draw[thick] plot file[scaling=0.1] {Grafik/tikz/fr_t.dat}  ;
.
.
```

Comment: Maybe use `pgfplots` for a substantial improvement on handling plots ?

Comment: In `TikZ`, `\begin{scope}[scale=??, shift=??] <your stuff> \end{scope}` is also an easy way to resize/relocate something !

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Jhor! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `pgfplots` for various reasons, but percusse comment is likely better.
With `tikz` only my answer would be to replace:

```
\draw[thick] plot file {Grafik/tikz/fr_t.dat} ;
```

by

```
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.5,yscale=0.1,xshift=30,yshift=25] % or whatever you want
\draw[thick] plot file {Grafik/tikz/fr_t.dat} ;
\end{scope}
```

or even simpler it you don't need the shift:

```
\draw[thick,color=blue] plot[y,yscale=0.5,xscale=0.1] file {Grafik/tikz/fr_t.dat} ;
```

The handling of the y-axis is more intricate. You must use differents variables. A fully functional MWE is :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \def\myfactor{10}
    \draw[step=0.2cm, very thin,color=black!20] (-0.01,-0.01) grid (2.09,1.19);
    \draw[->] (-0,0) -- (2.09,0) node[right] {$t$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.19) node[above] {$y_1$};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,2.1}  \node[anchor=north, font=\tiny] at (\x,0) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=1,decimalsymbol=comma]{\x}};
    \foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,1.1}  {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\myfactor*\y}
        \node[anchor=east, font=\tiny] at (0,\y) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=1,decimalsymbol=comma] {\yy}};
    }
\draw[thick,color=blue] plot[y,yscale=1/\myfactor,xscale=0.1] file {data.txt} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that gives, for a `data.txt` where `y` ranges from 0 to 10:
[image]

Of course you coud do the same thing for `x` .

Pending question : how to automatically get the value to which must be set the `\myfactor` macro.